# Starting udev before mountpoints in /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, init, udev, buildroot

I'm working on a buildroot image, and this image is using Busybox for init, along with devtmpfs and eudev for device initialization. There's no initramfs, the system boots directly into its permanent root. The `fstab` contains mountpoints that reference disks by partlabel, which require the udev rules for persistent disk naming to be run beforehand.

The buildroot eudev package creates a SysV init script at `/etc/init.d/S10udev` for this, and by default, it's started by `rcS`, after `inittab` handles the system's mountpoints. Allowing `rcS` to start udev won't work for this use case, because udev requires proc and sysfs to be mounted before it can work, which seems to indicate that `fstab` is a bad place for these mountpoints.

Is the proper way to handle this to move the mountpoints for proc and sysfs back into inittab, then manually start `S10udev` in `inittab` before `mount -a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either that, or mark these mount points as noauto (so mount -a won't try to mount them) and then mount them later (a later init script or from eudev)